# Get session context in plugin of ServiceStack

Tags: multithreading, session, authentication, plugins, servicestack

Demis! First of all, I would like to apologize if I spend your time for that goal. We have an solution, based on Service 4.0.34, with custom typed user session and RedisCacheClient.

The main idea of what we have to do is to logging of login in another service. It's worked, but sometimes (not always, but very often) we got a lot of login's records in log, at the same time (up to milliseconds) from one user session. We supposed, that it might be due to multithreading-character of service, and decided to using a queueing for log requests (for throttling doubles). 
In main configurer module I create a method, which is just a sender:

```
using (var redisPublisher = new RedisClient("localhost:6379"))
{
redisPublisher.PublishMessage(channelName, now);
}
```

Also, I wrote a receiver in plugin:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
            {
                var redisFactory = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379");

                using (var client = redisFactory.GetClient())
                using (var subscription = client.CreateSubscription())
                {
                    subscription.OnMessage = (channel, msg) =>
                    {
                        var session = cacheClient.GetAll<string>(new string[] { "id", "userAuthName", "licenseInfoLastSend" });
                        //AuthUserSession curSession = appHost.GetCacheClient().SessionAs<ChicagoUserSession>();
                    };
                    subscription.SubscribeToChannelsMatching(String.Format("{0}_*", LocatorProductId)); //blocks thread
                }
            });
```

So, I receive messages properly, but I couldn't get current session context. Is it possible to get a session in a plugin module ? Could you please help ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Session is tied to the current HTTP Request since the Session is [identified by the Session Cookies](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#permanent-and-temporary-session-ids) so they can only be resolved in the Context of a HTTP Request so you'll need access to `IRequest` to be able to resolve the Session using the `GetSession()` extension method, e.g:

```
var session = req.GetSession();
```

Inside ServiceStack `IRequest` is available in Request Filters or the `base.Request` property in Services, Razor Views, etc. There are also a number of ways to [access the IRequest outside of ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#saving-outside-a-service), e.g:

```
IHttpRequest httpReq = aspCtx.ToRequest(); //HttpContext
IHttpRequest httpReq = aspReq.ToRequest(); //MVC HttpRequestBase
IHttpRequest httpReq = listenerCtx.ToRequest(); //HttpListenerContext
```

In ASP.NET hosts you can access it statically via the singleton:

```
IHttpRequest httpReq = HostContext.AppHost.TryGetCurrentRequest();
```

But this still only works in the context of a HTTP Request when `HttpContext.Current` is not null, so wont work in background threads.

#### Accessing directly from ICacheClient

If you somehow got a hold of the session id in `ss-id` Cookie, you can resolve the Users Session directly from the Registered `ICacheClient` with:

```
var sessionKey = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(sessionId);
var session = cache.Get<IAuthSession>(sessionKey)
```